# UITabBarController slow loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have UITabBarController that has two tabs .Every tab load a file from internet .
so when I use

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: vv1,vv2, nil];
```

it download vv1 and vv2 at the same time so the program is very slow .

Is there away to download the first view vv1 and the download the second view by clicking it ?

Comment: what exactly downloaded from the internet ?

Comment: xml file becouse vv1 and vv2 are two tabelview and they will use these xml files to build themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use so called "lazy loading".

That would mean that, instead of doing the web stuff in the controller init method, you do that in

`[viewWillAppear][1]`,

or in your tab bar controller delegate

`[tabBarController:didSelectViewController][2]`.

This will surely reduce the lag when creating the tab bar.